# JQUERY, Warning Users that IE6 Is Not Supported are wanted

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins

I'm building an app and have no intentions of support IE6 at this time. To be fair to IE6, I want IE6 users to know that and not think the app was made by incompetent developers.

I was hoping a JQUERY Plug-In would be available that would provide a nice StackOverflow style alert at the top of the page, plug & play and I'm done. Surprisingly I'm not find such a plug-in.

Does anyone know of any plug-ins that could do the IE6 Detection and as a nice to have the warning? Seems like this is a common thing these days.

Thanks

Comment: also +1 for not supporting IE6. IT IS THE DEVIL

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Use Conditionals and CSS**

If you have a `header` include type file, (or something like the `layout` in Rails), just use the IE conditionals:

```
<body>
   <!--[if lte IE 6]>
      <div id="ie-warning">This site does not support IE6</div>
   <![endif]-->
```

And then use simple styling in your stylesheet.

**Or, if you really want jQuery:**

Here is a simple jQuery script that does what you want. Copy this and save it to `jquery.ie6.js`:

```
(function($){
   $(function(){
      var message = "This site does not support Internet Explorer 6. Please consider downloading a <a href='http://firefox.com'>newer browser</a>.",
          div = $('<div id="ie-warning"></div>').html(message).css({
                   'height': '50px',
                   'line-height': '50px',
                   'background-color':'#f9db17',
                   'text-align':'center',
                   'font-family':'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
                   'font-size':'12pt',
                   'font-weight':'bold',
                   'color':'black'
                }).hide().find('a').css({color:'#333'}).end();
      div.prependTo(document.body).slideDown(500);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

And then put this in the `head` (after the inclusion of jQuery of course) of your page:

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
   <script src="jquery.ie6.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

**DEMO**

[This demo](http://jsbin.com/axomi) is set to show in **all browsers**, but if you include it as I showed between the `if lte IE 6` conditional comments, it will *only* show up in IE6 and older versions of IE.

Comment: Much better than Javascript IMO.

Answer (score 4):

[IE6Update](http://ie6update.com/). It's lightweight and standalone; it doesn't need jQuery, but it will work just fine if you *are* using jQuery.

Comment: Its also devious and misleading.

Comment: it directs people to download newer version of IE.. would be better if it send them to get firefox ... lol

Comment: @Gaby, you can customize where it sends them actually. You can send them to Firefox if wanted. But of course you should send them to Apple Safari :D

Comment: @Doug, cool. I just show the example and taking into account the name i figured it was a fixed behaviour .. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i know this has been answered but i just found this jQuery plugin lets you put up a customised message.

http://politeiewarning.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

check out the **[jQuery.browser utility](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.browser)**

```
if ($.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version.substr(0,1)=='6') ...
```